# Use Passportjs Local for authentification with Axios Ajax Call And VueJs

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, axios, passport-local

I would like to build a dashboard with node and js view, and use a template engine like Handlebars or Pug, can i use PassportJs Local with Ajax Call

Answer (score 0):

We use PassportJs on the server-side as a middleware to authenticate users.

However, on the client-side, you call to endpoint e.g. `/login` which is unaware whether you are using PassportJs or not. Thus, one can say we do not use PassportJs on the client side.

Hence, you can definitely use Ajax to request an endpoint that may or may not be using PassportJs on the server-side.

Have a look at PassportJs [Documentation](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/downloads/html/)